# Sort table entries by date (dd.mm.yyyy)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to sort a table by the dates in a column.
The dates are in the format `dd.mm.yyyy`.

I am using the following code to sort the data within the `rng` Range-Object:

```
rng.Sort key1:=.Cells(HeaderRow, SortColumn), _
            order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
```

However, because of the format of the dates the sorting results in an alphabetically correct sort, but not date wise, since the strings are sorted from first to last character. An output would for example be:

```
10.07.2018    
10.08.2017    
11.06.2018
```

Is there any kind of option I can give the sorting so that it sorts the dates correctly?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I will just mention it's possible to avoid this issue altogether by temporarily modifying your regional settings so that dd.mm.yyyy is your default date format. Then, restart Excel so that changes are applied.

Comment: The best option is to properly enter the dates as dates (either `2018-07-09` or whatever Windows says your Short Date setting is, in Regional Settings), and then you can display them whatever way you want (even the existing way) but you can sort them and do calculations with them.

Comment: @ApplePie - Neat trick! Are you sure that will works even though this isn't a standard date format?

Comment: You could use an additional column in the table where you have a formula to have the date in the format dd.mm.yyyy to instead be in either a date or something that will sort correctly when sorted alphabetically, such as yyyy.mm.dd.  You could then sort by that additional column

Comment: @ashleedawg yes it does. Basically you hinted at it in your own comment. *"(either `2018-07-09` or whatever your Short Date setting is)*" - so logically, whatever your Short Date Windows format is, will also be the one Excel will use (as long as it is a legitimate format - which `dd.mm.yyyy` is), doesn't necessarily have to be standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those were actual dates then they would sort correctly; they must be text-that-look-like-dates. Convert the text-that-look-like-dates to actual dates, sort them and apply the desired number format.

```
With rng
    .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                   FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlDMYFormat)
    .Sort Key1:=.Cells(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    .NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
End With
```

Comment: Thank you @Jepped that was apparently exactly the case!
Your solution worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

With data like:

[image]

we must first convert to **true** dates and then sort:

```
Sub DateFixer()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, d As Date
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        With Cells(i, "A")
            v = .Text
            .Clear
            .NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
            arr = Split(v, ".")
            .Value = DateSerial(arr(2), arr(1), arr(0))
        End With
    Next i

    Range("A1:A" & N).Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End Sub
```

resulting in:

[image]

Comment: While the sample data did not show a column header label, the example code showed the sort with Header:=xlYes.